# Can the concavity be proved wrong by using following argument?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In one of the research paper, a function $$g(x)=\log (\exp (f(x)))$$

is proved to be concave by showing that $f(x)$ is concave. They claimed that if $f(x)$ is concave then the above composition of $\exp, \log$ will result in concavity of $g(x)$. I do not understand how this is true. But I know that log-sum-exp is a convex function. Which should mean that in the above function if $f
(x)$ is linear then $g(x)$ should be convex.

Comment: log(exp(f(x))) = f(x)log(exp) where log(exp) is a constanct... so g(x) = cf(x)
i used the rule (log(A^B)) = Blog(A)

Comment: @Sid thanks for your comment. But suppose if we have $\log E [\exp (f(x))]$ then will there be any difference? Here $E$ represents expectation with respect to some random variable other than $x$.

Comment: More precisely, $\log \circ \exp$ is the identity function (over the real, it doesn't work on the complex plane), so the equality in the original question just means $g = f$.

Comment: When working with a random function $f$ and putting an expectation in the middle, you get something quite different. I suggest you edit your question to make this clear from the start. Try to be precise about the origin of the variables and the source of randomness (right now, when I read "$\log E[\exp(f(x))]$" I see a real number, not some function which could be concave) . If you could give a link to the research paper, that would probably also make things clearer.